# How do I pull in the sku on a woocommerce product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, sku

I cannot figure out why this is just showing the variable name and isn't pulling in my sku from woocommerce. Do I need a global variable?

[image: screenshot]

## Change SKU to say part number on single product page

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );

function custom_woocommerce_template_single_meta(){
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="product_meta">
            <p><span class="sku_wrapper">Part Number: <span class="sku">'.$product_sku.'</span></span></p>
        <p><span class="posted_in">Category: <a href="https://pozzetta.com/product-category/photomask-carriers/" rel="tag">'.$product_category.'</a></span></p>
    </div>
    <?php
    return;
}
```

Comment: You're using a PHP variable in HTML. Change `'.$product_sku.'` to `<?php echo $product_sku ?>` , same with the other variable.

Comment: If `$product_sku` isn't defined in code, use the following code to get the SKU
`global $product; echo $product->get_sku();`

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out. Can you show me what you mean please?